# Visual Basic - My array values are not passing to the function what did I do wrong?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, function

```
' This will determine the pay precent based of a function
    Dim decRaisePercent As Decimal
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0

    For intCount = 1 To _intSizeOfArray

        decRaisePercent = RaisePercentage(_strRaiseId)
    Next

    For intCount = 1 To _intLifeOfItems
        _decNewPayRate(_intSizeOfArray) += _decPayRate(_intSizeOfArray) * decRaisePercent
    Next

Function RaisePercentage(ByRef strRaiseId() As String) As Decimal
    Dim RaisePercent As Decimal

    MessageBox.Show("test " & strRaiseId(_intSizeOfArray))
    Select Case strRaiseId(_intSizeOfArray)
        Case "A1"
            RaisePercent = 0.015D
        Case "A2"
            RaisePercent = 0.02D
        Case "A3"
            RaisePercent = 0.025D
    End Select

    Return RaisePercent
End Function
```

Hello my array values are not getting passed to the function and I can't figure out what is wrong. The values should be A1, A2, A1, and A3 but it is only returning A3 to me in the message-box. Can anyone help me figure out how stupid I am?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: they are all being passed, you have it hardcoded to just look at the last one: `Select Case strRaiseId(_intSizeOfArray)`  (assuming _intSizeOfArray is what the name infers)...then the logic to apply the raise is detached from the look up; all the raises will be based on the last value

Comment: Hmm Thank you I've fixed all my stuff now I had some other problems too in the rest of my program >.<. Thanks for the help my Issues solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression:

```
strRaiseId(_intSizeOfArray)
```

means, "Give me the item at the end of the array".

Instead of an array, change the function accept either the *index* in the array or the actual cell value of each item in the array.